# trying to use printf to decode unicode characters passed in as arguments

Tags: bash, unicode, printf

I am trying to printf some unicode codes that I pipe in like this

```
echo 0024 0025 | xargs -n1 echo # one code per line
  | xargs printf '\u%s\n'
```

hoping to get this

```
$
%
```

but this is what I get

```
printf: missing hexadecimal number in escape
```

After some trial and error, I actually have two smaller problems, and one kind-of makes sense and the other seems like a complete mystery.

---

Problem 1:

```bsh
printf '\u%s\n' 0024 0025
```

gives me this

```
-bash: printf: missing unicode digit for \u
\u0024
-bash: printf: missing unicode digit for \u
\u0025
```

Problem 2:

```bsh
> # use built-in for $
> printf '\u0024\n'
$
> # use exe for $
> which printf
/usr/bin/printf
> /usr/bin/printf '\u0024\n'
$
> # now use built-in for %
> printf '\u0025\n'
%
> # but look what happens when we use exe for % !!!!
> /usr/bin/printf '\u0025\n'
/usr/bin/printf: invalid universal character name \u0025
```

(using `>` for `$` so you can see the `$` in the output)

For some reason some characters work with exe version but some don't even though all work with built-in printf.

---

so here is a work-around that would work if it weren't for problem #2
(but might be quite a bit slower than my original idea)

```
echo 0024 0025 | xargs -n1 echo # one item per line
  | xargs -I {} printf '\u{}\n'
```

but due to problem #2, it kind of half works:

```
$ echo 0024 0025 | xargs -n1 echo | xargs -I {} printf '\u{}\n'
$
printf: invalid universal character name \u0025
```

($ comes out but % gets error)

---

So I guess my questions are:

-Is there any way of making printf work with the number code so that I can run printf once instead of once per argument with `-I`?

-What am I doing wrong that `printf` built-in doesn't mind, but `printf` exe doesn't like, but only for `%` and not for `$`?

Comment: Add an additional  `\\`   e.g.   `printf '\\u%s\n' 0024 0025`

Comment: I just get something like `\u0024`

Comment: Instead of struggling with chains of commands using unportable GNU extensions, just use perl `perl -CO -nle 'print chr hex for /[0-9a-fA-F]+/g'` and be done with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid the double-expansion problem (`\u` is processed before `%s`), you can use `%b`, at least in Bash `printf`:

```
printf '%b\n' \\u0024 \\u0025
```

You can pre-process your input in various ways:

```
set 0024 0025
printf '%b\n' "${@/#/\\u}"
```

The standalone `printf`, [as implemented in GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html), has the following restrictions on Unicode character specifications:

> `printf` interprets two character syntaxes introduced in ISO C 99: ‘`\u`’ for 16-bit Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) characters, specified as four hexadecimal digits *hhhh*, and ‘`\U`’ for 32-bit Unicode characters, specified as eight hexadecimal digits *hhhhhhhh*. `printf` outputs the Unicode characters according to the `LC_CTYPE` locale. Unicode characters in the ranges U+0000…U+009F, U+D800…U+DFFF cannot be specified by this syntax, except for U+0024 ($), U+0040 (@), and U+0060 (`).

This explains why you can’t produce `%` in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

The standard `printf` utility does not support `\uxxxx` escape sequences, see: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

Assuming this could work depends on extensions that might be present in a few implementations (e.g. in a `ksh` builtin), but cannot be expected to be supported in general. See the `printf` standard document.

Another problem seems to be your assumption that calling

```
printf '\u%s\n' 123
```

would result in the same as calling:

```
printf '\u123\n'
```

This does not work, as `printf` parses the format string element by element and does not see the expected format string.

So even if you are using `bash` to execute the script, you may just expect the `\uxx` backslash escape to be expanded if two hex digits follow and the escape sequence appears literally in the format string. If you like to have 4 hex digits expanded, you need to have `\Uxxxx` literally in the format string.